# how to get the lastest user status using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to use tweepy to get the most recent user status

My code is

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items():
    lastid = status.id
    laststatus = api.get_status(lastid).text
    break
```

it works. But I have to use a loop.
Is there any better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.items()` returns an iterator, so you can simply call `next()` to get the first item:

```
status = next(tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items())
```

This *could* raise a `StopIteration` exception if there are no items at all. You could add a default to `next()` to prevent that:

```
status = next(tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items(), None)
```